# How to properly inject dependencies with the built in Funq container?

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I have a cached repository

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void LogWebUsage(string html);
    IEnumerable<ApiKey> GetApiKeys();
    ApiKey GetApiKey(Guid key);
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger("API.Repository");

    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    public void LogWebUsage(string request)
    {
        Log.Debug(request);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ApiKey> GetApiKeys()
    {
        List<ApiKey> result = null;
        using (var db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            result = db.SelectParam<ApiKey>(q => q.Active);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public ApiKey GetApiKey(Guid key)
    {
        ApiKey result = null;
        using (var db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            result = (db.SelectParam<ApiKey>(q => q.Id == key)).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class CachedRepository : Repository
{
    public ICacheClient Cache { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerable<ApiKey> GetApiKeys()
    {
        const string cacheKey = "GetApiKeys";

        var result = Cache.Get<IEnumerable<ApiKey>>(cacheKey);

        if (result == null)
        {
            result = base.GetApiKeys();

            if (result.Any())
            {
                Cache.Add(cacheKey, result, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And I configure it like so.

```
//Register any dependencies you want injected into your services
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("DBConnstr"), true, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance));
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
container.Register<IRepository>(new CachedRepository());
container.RegisterAutoWired<CachedRepository>();
```

So what I was hoping for is that both the IDbConnectionFactory and ICacheClient would be injected at run-time, but they are null. How to you properly account for this type of dependency graph?

Thank you,
Stephen

**Updated**

After googling for a couple of hours I finally found a solution that works. Constructor injection though the config.

```
public class CachedRepository : Repository
{
    private ICacheClient Cache { get; set; }

    public CachedRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory, ICacheClient cache) : base(dbFactory)
    {
        Cache = cache;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ApiKey> GetApiKeys()
    {
        const string cacheKey = "GetApiKeys";

        var result = Cache.Get<IEnumerable<ApiKey>>(cacheKey);

        if (result == null)
        {
            result = base.GetApiKeys();

            if (result.Any())
            {
                Cache.Add(cacheKey, result, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
//Register any dependencies you want injected into your services
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("DBConnstr"), true, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance));        
container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => new MemoryCacheClient());
container.Register<IRepository>(c => new CachedRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>(), c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));
```

It works, but I'd still like to know how to wire up the property injection.

Take care,
Stephen... again

Comment: DbFactory is private in Repository class.

Comment: Good catch, fixed, but still null at run-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The APIs for [AutoWiring in ServiceStack's Funq IOC are here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#autowire-registration):

Using Generic API:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<MyType>();
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<MyType,IMyType>();
```

Using Run-time typed API:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(MyType));
container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(MyType),typeof(IMyType));
container.RegisterAutoWiredTypes(typeof(MyType),typeof(MyType2),typeof(MyType3));
```

So basically you can use any of the above APIs to auto-wire your dependencies, e.g:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new 
  OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("DBConnstr"), true, 
  SqlServerDialect.Provider));        

container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => new MemoryCacheClient());
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<CachedRepository,IRepository>(); //auto-wired
```